# DataTable Select with ascending rows

Tags: c#, datatable

Hi all I am having a datatable with some products as below

```
PordName   Price
 XYZ        123
 XYZ        120
 ABC        123
 ABC        120
```

I have written a select on this to display the selected productcode in ascending order,

`DataRow[] lRows = dt.Select("PordName='" + distinct.Rows[i]["PordName"].ToString() + "'", "PriceASC");`

But this is not giving me proper results can some one help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to chnage your code like this:

Try this:

```
var condition = string.Format("PordName='{0}'", distinct.Rows[i]["PordName"]);
var sortorder = "Price ASC";
var rows = dt.Select(condition,sortorder);
```

Comment: Even though I added single quotes for the first set of rows it is displaying as per required but for the second product it is not displaying as required

Comment: Hi Amit I need to filter it based on product and for that product I need to select the least price

Answer (score -1):

Price and ASC write together,Please not write together